# How to use passed arguments as default parameter values in Python?

Tags: python, input, arguments, variadic-functions

Given a function with multiple arguments, where all but the first one are variable.

E.g.:
`def f(a, b = .., ...)`

I am looking for minimalist python-code that realizes the intuitive code below:

`def f(a, b = a, ...)`

Hence, I could not find any satisfying answers I am asking here although I am without doubts that the answers to this question have been given already somewhere - in that case i apologize.
Cheers!

I specify by another example my desired functionality again intuitively by wrong code:

```
def f(a,b,c, d = 0, e = [], f = b, g = c, h = a):
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want the default of one parameter to be the value passed to another?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> the expression [used as default parameter value] is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.

So what you are trying to achieve would not work so simply because default parameter values are computed only once at the function definition, not at every call.

Instead, you can set all default parameter values to `None` and test for this value in the body of the function:

```py
def func(a, b, c, d = 0, e = [], f = None, g = None, h = None):
    f = b if f == None else f
    g = c if g == None else g
    h = a if h == None else h
```

Comment: I don't think so. Also you should probably remove the answer you posted as a comment:)

Comment: - a touch of fastidiousness I wanna respect :D